# Cannot find the persistence.xml

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I have the following persistence.xml inside the as.jar file. And the as.jar file is in the manifest of the project. But when I build the project, there is error message that the asJPA cannot be find. I would like to ask why and how to fix the issue.

```
<persistence-unit name="asJPA" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/us_ds</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle10Platform" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebSphere_6_1" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="NONE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.session-event-listener" value="edu.polyu.srs.listener.SrsSessionEventListener" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Your persistence.xml should be in META-INF/persistence.xml in as.jar

Comment: Thx for the reply. But the as.jar is used by many projects. It's hard to extract the persistence.xml in the as.jar and put into meta-inf folder of my current project. If I do so, I need to do in all projects that depend on the as.jar. It's a disaster.  Is there any way to achieve the goal?

Comment: It is enough to store persistence.xml in `META-INF` folder inside the as.jar. It must be found in such folder anywhere in the class path. Where do you store the persistence.xml file inside the as.jar?